# Command 'update-database' is not working in .NET 6 Entity Framework for API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Command `update-database` is not working in .NET 6 entity framework for API. Console window displays an error

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

after I run the command `update-database`. Command `add-migration` is working fine.

`appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database=MovieContext; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
}
```

`Program.cs` file:

```
using AspNetCoreWebApi6.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MovieContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MovieContext")));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[image]

Comment: https://medium.com/net-core/build-a-restful-web-api-with-asp-net-core-6-30747197e229

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a connection string named "MovieContext" instead of "DefaultConnection"

Comment: In both json and cs files?

Comment: Either rename your connection string in json to "MovieContext", or use "DefaultConnection" in the .cs file, the important part is that they are the same